# What is the difference between "for i" and "for i in 1 2 3 4" in shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting

I had to print all the arguments parsed in a shell script on a different line. I wrote a script as

```
for i in 1 2 3 4 5
do
   echo $i
done
```

but this prints

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

even if i parse the arguments as "10 20 30 40 50"

and one code on the internet

```
for i
do
   echo $i
done
```

this code prints the arguments correctly.

Can someone explain me why that code works but mine doesn't?

Also how can I use the value of one variable ($i) as the variable name to print something else. like

```
i=1
$($i)
```

should print the value of $1.

Comment: Try `for i in hello world lalala hohoho; do echo "$i"; done`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`for i` is equivalent to `for i in "$@"`

From Bash `help for`:

> ```
> for: for NAME [in WORDS ... ] ; do COMMANDS; done
>    Execute commands for each member in a list.
>
>    The 'for' loop executes a sequence of commands for each member in a
>    list of items.  If 'in WORDS ...;' is not present, then 'in "$@"' is
>    assumed.  For each element in WORDS, NAME is set to that element, and
>    the COMMANDS are executed.
> ```

> If `in WORDS ...;` is not present, then `in "$@"` is assumed

If you want to get the variable from a variable, use indirect expansion:

```
set -- arg1 arg2 arg3 foo
for i in 3 4 1 2
do
    echo "${!i}"
done
# Output: arg3 foo arg2 arg1
```

Comment: Yeah, I read the indirect expansion somewhere, but I am unable to implement this in my code. Can you write a sample for my code in the for loop with indirect expansion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, understood. I was using "sh file.sh 10 20 30" instead of "bash file.sh 10 20 30". Thank you very much.

Comment: @Gaurav You're welcome. Next time pay attention to these details (and don't tag your question with `bash` if you're writing POSIX-compilant sh scripts).

Comment: My bad. My teacher asked us to write bash scripts but didn't tell us to use bash in the terminal. I found that out later by googling.